# When should I split my table for faster lookup?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table with 500k rows that are only read (a lot, by multiple users). I was wondering if splitting the database in two by, let's say "date of birth" of the rows, would be more efficient.

I have half of the table that will be queried a lot more (birthdate>40). So splitting it by birthdate would allow me to directly check into a smaller subset (by simply checking if my element is >40). Is this method improving anything?

Comment: I assume you mean a "table", not a database (a database contains multiple tables). You probably only need an index to support your queries. Splitting up such a small table won't be necessary.

Comment: edited! my bad thanks!
At what point do such mechanisms become relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index solves your problem. Spliting a table by storing different sections of it only complicates things.

Answer (score 1):

SiWM is right. Don't split your table, especially given 500k is not really a big number by today's standard. As an addition to SiWM's suggestion, I would recommend you check which columns are in the WHERE clause when the table is queried, and make sure these are indexed.

Comment: I understand, however it seems that at some point it might be a potential solution? At what sizes should i start thinking about such things and what is the theory behind it? scaling of SELECT as function of N ?

Comment: The point where this would be a potential solution is the point where you should move to a Big Data framework anyway, such as Apache Spark/Hadoop. From my personal experience the breaking point is somewhere around hundreds of millions of rows. 500k row is nowhere near that. Don't even think about manually splitting tables before you tried https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html and this

Answer (score 1):

You can also cluster the table using the main index used (with a cron job), especially if you need to return several rows from a single query.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-cluster.html

Initial set up:

```
    CLUSTER [VERBOSE] table_name [ USING index_name ]
```

Re-cluster:

```
    CLUSTER table_name
```